What is the "family tree" of translations of Euclid's Elements?
I once saw a beautiful "family tree" of copies or translations of Euclid's Elements, starting with Greek versions, going on to Arabic translations made in Baghdad and elsewhere, and then going on to Latin translations, and perhaps beyond.  I can't find it now.  Can anyone find this for me?
I'm less interested in English editions than the earlier history.

I turns out Murdoch (1971) does contain a quite detailed transmission diagram for the Elements. I changed my answer to include it.

Here is the timeline compiled by biochemist Herbert M. Sauro:

from his own version of Euclid Elements: Book I: A New Edition,
Ambrosius Publishing (2023), page 12, Fig. 1. Solid lines mean certain, dotted are uncertain but probable. The chart can also be found on his Google site on Euclid: https://euclid.analogmachine.org/early-history
For the full list check Thomas L. Heath, Euclid Vol 1 (1908), Introduction chapter.

Thanks, that's very nice!  The one I saw had more detail in the roughly 340-year-long stretch labeled "Arabic (~800 AD)".  I believe there's a lot known about Arabic translations of Euclid's Elements, which then somehow got to people like Adelard, Gerard and Robert.   I may have read about it in some book about the Graeco-Arabic translation movement.

Not likely the sought answer, but this diagram has somewhat more detail on Arabic translation and transmission of Euclid's Elements:
Tropiano, S. G. A short introduction to the Euclid's Elements for high school students.

Murdoch J. (1971), ‘Euclid: Transmission of the Elements’, Dictionary of Scientific Biography, New York: Scribner, vol. 4, 437–59 contains a detailed transmission diagram on p. 458-459:



The charts above are great, but someone pointed me to this extremely detailed family tree:

Euclid: The Elements.

There is a slider called "Clarification"; as you reduce the number here from 10/10 toward 0/10 you see fewer editions and the family tree becomes easier to comprehend.  There is another slider below that, where you can adjust the range of dates you're interested in.  If you click on some of the editions you will be sent to online versions of these books!
The page is complex and I don't fully understand how to use it.  For more information, in French, go here:

Bernard Vitrac and Alain Herreman, MÉδÉE: Manuscrits et Éditions
des Éléments d'Euclide.


Professor Baez: Do you know if Isaac Barrow's edition appear in the chart?

Very nice. I did check Vitarc's edited volumes and commentary for transmission diagrams but this table does not seem to be included in the print versions as best I could discern. It's good to know it exists. Clearly this is the proper successor to Murdoch (1971).

José Hdz. Stgo - if you use the search feature and search under "Barrow" it seems to be there, but I find the website hard to use.
